# Отображение PDF

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть ли возможность загрузки и отображения PDF-документов в Qt5?

Прочитал про возможность загрузки с использованием `QWebView`, но следующий код не работает:

```
m_pHtmlBrowser->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::WebAttribute::PluginsEnabled, true);
m_pHtmlBrowser->load(QUrl("http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf"));
```

ОС: Ubuntu. Но интересует кросс-платформенное решение.

Answer (score 2):

Qt не умеет показывать PDF, для этого нужно использовать стороннюю библиотеку. Насколько мне известно, наиболее популярной библиотекой является [poppler](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/poppler/), у него есть обвязка для Qt.

Comment: Спасибо. Нашел в принципе решение с использованием PDF.js - на тестовых данных `QWebView` отработал отлично. Попробую через него реализовать вывод.